# Any way to connect to a webpage, call JS functions, and then download the html using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out a way to connect to a webpage, run JS functions on that webpage (Which will modify the html), and then download that modified html. I'm not sure it is possible this way, and if it isn't, is there any other way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://phantomjs.org/download.html is what you're looking for.

How you'd run JS:

```
$response = exec('path/to/phantomjs script.js');
```

Additionally, look at this: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs